# Assessing TB mortality due to M. bovis vs M. tuberculosis infections in pre-19th century England?

Tags: medicine

Over the years, and long before the discovery of the causative agent, tuberculosis was known by various names, including "phthisis" and "consumption". Robert Koch discovered Mycobacteria in 1882.

We now know that there are several species of Mycobacteria that cause tuberculosis, the key ones historically in England being *Mycobacterium tuberculosis* and *Mycobacterium bovis* (the latter of which causes bovine tuberculosis and can also cause disease in humans).

Pre-nineteenth century historical records will not, of course, have possibly distinguished between TB in people caused by *M. tuberculosis* versus *M. bovis*. However, have there been any studies to retrospectively assess what proportion of TB in people was caused by each of these organisms? In other words, has it been possible to estimate the human mortality due to each of these organisms in pre-nineteenth century England?